# How to hash String using SHA-256 with only 32characters?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha256

I am using `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils` for sha256 implementation like below.

`DigestUtils.sha256Hex("myString")`

this is returning 64characters hash String. But I need only 32characters hashed String.

How to hash the String value using SHA-256 with only 32 characters hashed value?

Comment: That wouldn't be a SHA-256 anymore, would it?

Comment: you're getting the hex representation of the hash, so every character of the result just represents 4 bit of the hash. Therefore the result is 64 characters long for 256 bits. The byte representation `public static byte[] sha256(byte[] data)` would be 32 bytes long but only binary (non-printable). With base64 encoding you would end up with 44 characters. What do you really want/need?

Comment: I want String with 32 characters after encode

Comment: If you need a SHA-256 hash but you want to have only 32 characters in the result, then what you're asking is impossible, because a SHA-256 always contains 64 chars in hex representation. Can you explain why you need 32 characters? What's the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: How to make a 32 hex chars GUID from a SHA256 of 64 hex chars ? From what i see, this is impossible ???

Answer (score -1):

As the name SHA-**256** implies, the hash consists of **256 bits**, i.e. 64 characters (*256 / 4 = 64*) in the hex representation.
If you want 32 characters, you'd have to use the [MD5 algorithm](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex-java.lang.String-):

```java
DigestUtils.md5Hex("myString")
```

But if you **really** need to use 32 characters from a 64 character string, you can use `String#substring()` - (which I would definitely not recommend, rather use [MD5](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex-java.lang.String-)):

```java
String hash64 = "9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08";
String hash32 = hash64.substring(0, 32): // 9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015
```

Comment: If you cut off the last 32 characters, then what you end up with is ofcourse not a SHA-256 hash anymore.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to truncate cryptographic hash functions like SHA2. Do not use MD5.